# What's the correct way of sending a LinkOutSuggestion with an openUrlAction?

Tags: actions-on-google

According to the [documentation for LinkOutSuggestion](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#linkoutsuggestion) the `url` option is now deprecated in favor of `openUrlAction`. However, when looking at the documentation for [Suggestion chips](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#suggestion_chip) and the [LinkOutSuggestion class](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/master/src/service/actionssdk/conversation/response/linkout.ts#L45) i don't see a way to add openUrlAction parameter to the RichResponse object.

This is example:

```
conv.ask(new LinkOutSuggestion({
  name: 'Suggestion Link',
  url: 'https://assistant.google.com/',
}));
```

How can we add a LinkOutSuggestion with an openUrlAction?

Answer (score -1):

Code for using [OpenUrlAction](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_response.openurlaction.html) in LinkOutSuggestion

```
conv.ask(new LinkOutSuggestion({

    name: 'Suggestion Link',
    url: new OpenUrlAction({url : 'https://assistant.google.com/'}).url,

  }));
```

Make sure you have done this before using the above:

```
const {
  LinkOutSuggestion,
  OpenUrlAction
} = require('actions-on-google');
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This code is basically just passing the url as a parameter after taking it from and instantiated `OpenUrlAction`, what i want is to actually pass the OpenUrlAction to the LinkOutSuggestion in the response, and that seems to not be possible with the current version of the sdk, even though the documentation for the api says it should